# Ag-Grid text editor not closing on click out

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-grid with a column set up to allow editing with the default text editor and to close the editor when the user clicks anywhere outside of the editor field. However, the editor does not close when I click below the grid.

I took a pass at debugging inside of the ag-grid code, and what I noticed is that when I click below the grid, I'm actually clicking outside of the `<body>` of the page. The `<html>` element is getting the click event. This causes ag-grid to think that it is dealing with a custom editor due to the following code in `ag-grid/grid-community-modules/core/src/ts/widgets/popupService.ts`:

```
    public isElementWithinCustomPopup(el: HTMLElement): boolean {
        const eDocument = this.gridOptionsService.getDocument();
        while (el && el !== eDocument.body) {
            if (el.classList.contains('ag-custom-component-popup') || el.parentElement === null) {
                return true;
            }
            el = el.parentElement;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Note that when `el` is the `<html>` element, `el.parentElement` is null, and we `return true` for this check. But I am not using a custom editor (as per my grid config below).

I think I can work around this by adding some sort of overlay while editing to catch the click events, but it looks like it might be a bug in ag-grid code (I think the `while` loop needs to also check if `el` is the `<html>` element). Or else is there some other setting I should be using that would override this behavior?

Here is my HTML template:

```
<h3>My Page</h3>
<div>
    <ag-grid-angular
        class="ag-theme-fresh"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
    </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

And here is my grid configuration:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent {
    public gridOptions: GridOptions = {
        rowHeight: 35,
        headerHeight: 35,
        rowMultiSelectWithClick: true,
        suppressCellFocus: true,
        suppressMovableColumns: true,
        suppressMenuHide: true,
        suppressContextMenu: true,
        stopEditingWhenCellsLoseFocus: true,
        onCellEditingStopped: this.updateData(),
        defaultColDef: {
            sortable: true,
            filter: true,
            resizable: true
        },
        columnDefs: [ {
            field: 'cohort',
            width: 100,
            editable: true,
            cellEditor: 'agTextCellEditor',
            cellEditorPopup: true,
            cellEditorPopupPosition: 'under'
        } ],
        onGridReady: (event) => this.loadDataFromApi(event),
    };

    private loadDataFromApi(event) {
       // get data, call event.api.setRowData 
    }

    private updateData() {
        // call api to update data
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around, I was able to add a fixed-position `<div>` with full height and width to be sure that any clicks on the page are handled by an element with in the `<body>`. The HTML becomes:

```
<div class="editor-event-grabber"></div>
<h3>My Page</h3>
<div>
    <ag-grid-angular
        class="ag-theme-fresh"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
    </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

Then add some `css` to position it:

```
.editor-event-grabber {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```